# How to encode/decode Tweets in Hindi language from Twitter to display in Hindi font when written to a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, utf-8

I am trying to crawl Twitter for Hindi Tweets using Hindi emotion words(eg.खुशी, गुस्सा) to get Tweets with these words using python 2.7. I am using the Streaming API and the code for it is below

```
import codecs
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        saveFile = codecs.open('TweetPrjkhushh.txt', 'a', 'utf-8')
        saveFile.write(data)
        saveFile.write('\n')
        saveFile.close()
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

t = u"खुशी"
stream.filter(languages=["hi"],track=[t])
```

I get tweets text in Unicode like this:

```
{"text":"RT @guru9899: \u092f\u0947 \u092c\u0947\u091c\u093e\u0928 \u0928\u0947 \u092c\u094b\u0932\u093e \u092f\u093e @abpnewshindi  \u0915\u0940 \u092e\u0941\u0939\u0940\u092e \u0939\u0948 ??? \u0939\u093e\u0925 \u0935\u093e\u092a\u0938 \u092d\u0940 \u0924\u094b \u0916\u0940\u0902\u091a \u0938\u0915\u0924\u0947 \u0925\u0947 ??? \u091c\u092c\u0930\u0926\u0938\u094d\u0924\u0940 \u0925\u094b\u0921\u093c\u0940 \u0939\u0948 \ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02\ud83d\ude02 https:\/\/t.co\/BE0gSEj\u2026"}
```

I want to display it in Hindi font when we open the file where I am saving the tweets, but using codecs and utf-8 encoding while saving doesn't help. What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks ok. How are you reading the output file?

Comment: I am reading it like this:                                                                       with codecs.open('TweetPrjkhushh.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    input = f.read()

print input

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a dict.

Change your code to specify the key entry of `data`:

```
def on_data(self, data):
    print data["text"]
    saveFile = codecs.open('TweetPrjkhushh.txt', 'a', 'utf-8')
    saveFile.write(data["text"])
    saveFile.write('\n')
    saveFile.close()
    return True
```